# Find a specific type of font on (WinForm) RichTextBox in VB

Tags: vb.net

I need help from someone to get started. I have a (WinForm) RichTextBox with my text:

```
RichTextBox1.text = "I'm noob in Stackoverflow" 'the word "noob" is strikeout
```

What is the easiest way to find a certain kind of font in the middle of my RichTextBox?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://vbcity.com/forums/t/162314.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Setting up the text in a richtextbox...

```
    RichTextBox1.Text = "I'm noob in Stackoverflow"
    RichTextBox1.Select(5, 4) 
    RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = _
       New Font(RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.Name, _ 
       RichTextBox1.SelectionFont.Size, FontStyle.Strikeout)
```

and testing some text for its font...

```
    RichTextBox1.Select(5, 4)
    Dim FNT As Font = RichTextBox1.SelectionFont
    Dim IsStrikout As Boolean = FNT.Strikeout
```

Comment: Thanks...and if I need to do this in all my text...i must use fors and ifs to analyse all my sentence,dont i